# How to make the wheel turn on the server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I received homework which involves turning the wheel. The circle consists of 54 balls separated by a 4 pixel gap. The task is to draw one of 54 numbers to which the degree of rotation is assigned. Then within 15 seconds the wheel must make two turns. That is 720deg + the value drawn.

This is a "Rotation of Wheel system". Using Node.js to generate a varaible for client. I'm using Socekt.IO to send a message to a client.

//This is values for the rotation degree for numbers

```
function Rotate(data, last);
let INITIAL_VALUE = last;
let FINAL_RESULT = data += 720 - INITIAL_VALUE;
const FRAME_PER_SECOND = 120;
const DURATION_WHEEL = 15000;

setTimeout(function(){

    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        var CURRENT_TIME = new Date().getTime() - start;
        x = easeOutQuart(CURRENT_TIME, INITIAL_VALUE, FINAL_RESULT - INITIAL_VALUE, DURATION_WHEEL);
        io.sockets.emit('angle', x % 360);

        if (CURRENT_TIME >= DURATION_WHEEL) {   
            var cut = x % 360;
            io.sockets.emit('angle', cut);

                        LAST_ANGLE = cut;

            clearInterval(timer);
            EndRound();
        }
    }, 1000 / FRAME_PER_SECOND);
}, 500);
}

function easeOutQuart(t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d;
    return -c * t*(t-2) + b;
}
```

I expect two turns including the drawn value. Every now and then, I don't get one whole turn.

Comment: so you're emitting every 8.333ms - perhaps that's too quick - what does the client side code look like?

Comment: by the way ... the `io.sockets.emit('angle', cut);` is redundant as that is exactly the same as the last angle sent before the `if` test anyway

Comment: Client-side code: `socket.on('angle', function(data){
    var css = 'transform: rotate('+parseFloat(data)+'deg)';
    $(".rl-main-wheel").attr('style', css);
}); `

Comment: try changing your frame per second to something like 30. If that works consistently, then increase it slowly ... I don't think there's any reason to go above 60 though

Comment: I set 120FPS on this value because there was no lag at this value. Can I on the server side somehow eliminate lag?

Comment: I thought the issue was in the client. Did you even try the suggestion? What do you mean by "lag". anyway. I think you do have "lag", in the animation. You're trying to animate at 120fps. Why? A browsers requestAnimationFrame only gives you 60fps - there's a reason for that